# add_query_arg to look up page title

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, terms

I'm trying to get the code below to look up the status name, i.e. *new*, *open*, *pending* or *resolved* with the word *ticket* together to find pages called new tickets, open tickets etc.

```
$ticket_status = get_terms('ticket_status', 'orderby=description&hide_empty=0');
echo '<ul class="numberlist">';
if ($ticket_status) : foreach($ticket_status as $status) :

    if (!isset($counts[$status->slug])) :
        $counts[$status->slug] = '0';
    endif;
    echo '<li><a href="'.
        add_query_arg($status->name, 'tickets').
        '">'.$status->name.'<span>'.$counts[$status->slug].'</span></a></li>';
```

Comment: What is in your `$status` variable? have you tried to `var_dump($status);` it?

Comment: Also, you'd probably want to switch the two, so that `'tickets'` is the first parameter.

Comment: Swapping gives  me `http://localhost/?page_id=38&tickets=pending`

Comment: I would like to find a page called pending tickets

Comment: this takes me to a loop search for tickets meeting the status    `<a href="'.add_query_arg('assigned_to', get_current_user_id(), get_term_link($status->slug, 'ticket_status')).'">`    I still want to look for page

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what are your exact status slug and title and page title are, but something like this should work, if I understand you correctly:

```
$page = get_page_by_title($status->name." tickets");
echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($page->ID).'">'
      .$status->name.' (<span>'.$counts[$status->slug].'</span>)</a></li>';
```

Comment: Great that works a treat only grip is the links look like this new() open() pending() resolved()    `if (!isset($counts[$status->slug])) :
    $counts[$status->slug] = '0';
   endif;
   
   $page = get_page_by_title($status->name." tickets");
echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($page->ID).'">'
      .$status->name.' (<span>'.$counts[$status->slug].'</span>)</a></li>';

  endforeach; endif;
  echo '</ul>'; 
   `

Comment: but removing the brackets around the span fixes that!  Thanks alvaro.d

Comment: Hmm, it should show (0) or (n) for $counts[$status_slug] = n. Can you please mark the question as asnwered then?